# how to navigate to viewcontroller in xamarin.ios on rowselect delegate method

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am working for navigation from Table View to View Controller, when I am clicking row I got exception as `System.NullReferenceException has been thrown Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Here is code:

```
    UITableViewController _contact;

    public Contactlist(UITableViewController contact)
    {

      _contact=contact;

    }

public override void Row Selected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{

   // Error System.NullReferenceException
   _contact.NavigationController.PushViewController(new incomingscreen(),true);

}
```

please help

Answer (score 0):

A ViewController's NavigationController property will be null unless the ViewController is contained within a NavigationController.

```
window.RootViewController = new UINavigationController(new MyTableViewController());
```

Comment: i am getting window ,RootViewController and UINavigationViewController does not exist in current context ,if any sample code is there just post and point to links

Comment: sorry, it's just UINavigationController.  That code snippet is assuming you're setting up your root controller in AppDelegate.cs.